# Is there a way to hide a Chrome browser tab via an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have a software which uses a browser tab to hold the connection between client and server.
Users accidentally close the tab and have connection issues.

I want to program a Chrome extension which scans all new tabs. When this special tab is identified, I want to move this to a new window and hide this window, so that the user can't close the tab by mistake.

Is this possible with a Chrome extension?

Thanks.

Comment: Moving/extracting a tab is [possible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-move) but there's no API for hiding so you'll have to write a separate external utility that can do it and call this utility via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this makes sense. I think I could either trigger a custom-url-handler in my extension, or use the proposed nativeMessaging solution.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you have an additional hint how I could identify the Chrome window from the external application? -- Would be nice when I can provide some parameter to the program about which window to hide on the Windows OS level.  Something like Windows ID would probably not be available from the Chrome APIs, hmm?

Comment: I guess you can add a unique random text to the title using a content script in the active tab of that minimized window, then pass that title to the utility.

Comment: I think something like this is very doable, just not sure how... see: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panic-button/faminaibgiklngmfpfbhmokfmnglamcm?hl=en